# I wonder if I can use Prolog to do resolution reasoning

Tags: math, prolog, logic

I'm very new to mathematical logic and I'm trying to learn Prolog recently, I wonder if I can use Prolog to do resolution reasoning, e.g., to do the following reasoning:

1. knowing that ∀x.(sheep(x)→eatgrass(x))
2. knowing that ∀x.(deadsheep(x)→¬eatgrass(x))
3. to prove ∀x.(deadsheep(x)→¬sheep(x))

what I'm trying to realize is that write code like the following:

```
eatgrass(X) :- sheep(X).
false       :- deadsheep(X), eatgrass(X).
sheep(X).
deadsheep(X).
```

and get query answer 'false' when query

```
?- sheep(a),deadsheep(a).
```

It seems in Prolog I cannot realize something like line 2:

```
false :- deadsheep(X), eatgrass(X).
```

so I wonder if there is a way to do the reasoning like above mentioned in Prolog, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
false :- deadsheep(X), eatgrass(X).
```

is an *integrity constraint*.

While exploitable in a more resolution-based theorem prover, you cannot have this in Prolog because it's not a clause (neither a definite clause, aka. Horn clause, i.e. without negation in the body, nor a general clause, i.e. with 'negation as failure' in the body).

(As an example, the Markgraf Karl Resolution Theorem Prover of 1981 indeed could handle integrity constraints)

Integrity constraints can be found in *Answer Set Programming* systems, which find solutions to logic programs in a way quite different from Prolog: not by SLDNF proof search but by finding sets of ground facts that are a model of the program (i.e. that make every statement of the program *true*).

You program with

`sheep(X), deadsheep(X).` does not make sense (because it says "everything is a sheep" and "everythinh is a deadsheep"), but if you change this to:

```
eatgrass(X) :- sheep(X).
false       :- deadsheep(X), eatgrass(X).
sheep(flopsy).
deadsheep(flopsy).
```

then this program is a way of asking: is there a set of ground atoms (in the logic sense) based on `eatgrass/1`, `sheep/1`, `deadsheep/1` that is a model for the program, i.e. for which every statement of the program becomes true?.

Well, there is not, because we need

```
sheep(flopsy).
deadsheep(flopsy).
```

to be true, so clearly `eatgrass(flopsy)` needs to be true too, and this violates the integrity constraint.

What you can do is test the integrity constraint as part of your query:

Program:

```
eatgrass(X) :- sheep(X).
sheep(flopsy).
deadsheep(flopsy).
```

Query: *Is there a sheep X such that X is not both eating grass and dead?*

```
?- sheep(X),\+ (deadsheep(X),eatgrass(X)).
```

In this case, no.

Comment: @LiDanyuan Why are there no integrity constraints? Because they do not fit into Prolog's processing principle., which is very "goal directed" and is strongly biased towards "programming" rather than "theorem proving". You would need some kind of general supervisor that gets triggered whenever new facts are labeled true during proof search that cannot be true at the same time. That's rather costly and makes the "programming" part much less attractive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If  I may ask, why 'false :- deadsheep(X), eatgrass(X).' is not a Horn clause, as what I can find on Wiki https://en.wikipedia.ahau.cf/wiki/Horn_clause, it seems to me that this is a Horn clause without a positive literal that sometimes is called goal clause.

Comment: Compare with the integrity constraints in a relational database. They are far from general logical expressions plus we know exactly when to check them (whenever updates happen) and for which facts (the updated records).

Comment: @LiDanyuan I see Wikipedia is classifying the `FALSE <- BODY` clause also as Horn. I would rather not do that. `FALSE <- BODY` is a confusing way of expressing that your query (or goal) is the `BODY`, or in other words, in the higkly idealistic setting of classical logic, that if you add `FALSE <- BODY` to your program, you can derive a logical contradiction (by resolution refutation), and thus BODY must be true. But nobody thinks like that...

Comment: But yes, apparently this falls under "Horn Clause": [The Semantics of Predicate Logic as a Programming Language](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rak/papers/kowalski-van_emden.pdf)

Comment: Hi, I've tried the program you provided using swi-prolog online, but it failed with message 'procedure ` \+(A,B)' does not exist', I wonder if it is allowed to use negation in query in prolog, or I might have done something wrong, thanks!

Comment: There are parenthesis missing, I believe it should be `sheep(X),\+( (deadsheep(X),eatgrass(X)) ).`

Comment: Ah the pitfalls of the Prolog syntax! I should have tried that in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

As @David Tonhofer suggested, integrity constraints can be found in Answer Set Programming systems, I found [potassco's clingo](https://potassco.org/) is a great tool to solve my problem, so I put the example code here in case someone may need a similar one:

```
eatgrass(X) :- sheep(X).
            :- deadsheep(X), eatgrass(X).
sheep(shawn).
deadsheep(shawn).
```

The second line is an integrity constraint which can be supported in clingo, and if you run this program using [clingo online](https://potassco.org/clingo/run/), clingo will tell you this is unsatisfiable, which suggests the reasoning is correct.